# deleting from table using mysql

Tags: java, mysql

guys I have following table:

```
+--------------------------------------------------+
|id |  type    |   name   |    parent  |  group_id |
+--------------------------------------------------+
| 1 |  special |   name1  |    0       |  21       |
| 2 |  Group   |   name2  |    1       |  19       |
| 3 |  Group   |   name3  |    1       |  22       |
| 4 |  special |   name4  |    0       |  89       |
+--------------------------------------------------+
```

and `right_id` in `table2` references on `id` in `bo_right`

I want to delete rows where `name = name2` and `name3`. So how to do that?

**My own solution is:**

```
delete from bo_right WHERE name ='name2' AND name = 'name3';
```

but it doesn't work .. any solution .. thanks

Comment: can you put your java code?, and ypur error if exist

Comment: For your future questions: "it does not work" is not a sufficient problem description! It is quite obvious here, but most people stop putting effort in a question that doesn't state clearly the perceived behavior in contrast to the expected.

Comment: name can't be both name2 and name3. Replace 'AND' with 'OR'.

Comment: You could simply change the `AND` to `OR` in order to delete all the rows haven the `name=  'name2'` OR `name = 'name3'`. Slightly more elegant is the given solution from @Mahesh Madushanka where SQL searches for the appearence of the value from column `name` in a given set.

Answer (score 7):

**Change `AND` to `OR`:**

```
delete from bo_right WHERE name ='name2' OR name = 'name3';
```

**Or you can use `IN`:**

```
delete from bo_right WHERE name IN ('name2', 'name3');
```

Answer (score 4):

You can simply change the `AND` in your query to an `OR`. For a more elegant and compact readable way you could use:

```
DELETE from bo_right WHERE name in ('name2', 'name3');
```

to search for the appearence of the value from column `name` in a given set.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `OR` instead of `AND` like this:

```
delete from bo_right WHERE name ='name2' OR name = 'name3';
```

You want to delete the rows where the name is `"name2"` **OR** `"name3"`.
It is not possible that the name is `"name2"` **AND** `"name3"` at the same time

Answer (score 0):

Just use :

```
delete from bo_right WHERE  name in('name2','name3');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `in condition` to delete the record as follows:

```
delete from bo_right WHERE name in('name2', 'name3');
```